# Subdomain points to public IP, when used internal it doesn't load, only externally, what can be done?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, subdomain

We created a subdomain for a website hosted in our internal server. In GoDaddy we set up the subdomain to point to the public IP address, but when we try to access the link internally it doesn't load (because it needs the internal IP to access it) What can be done in this case?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/260014/access-internal-ip-using-public-ip, http://superuser.com/questions/444206/access-internal-server-using-external-ip, in short: use NAT loopback if your router supports it, otherwise use a record in your internal DNS server, ultimately use the hosts file per machine.

Comment: Great! Thank your for your time and support! I was able to use NAT loopback!

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to provide different information to internal DNS clients than those publicly available to the world. For that you need to have internal [DNS server](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/) or [DNS proxy](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) that will respond with internal IP address, and your internal clients need to be configured to use that internal DNS server. Specific steps to achieve all this depend on your environment.

The other option is to create another DNS record (for example subdomain-internal.example.com) that will point to private IP address, and use that from internal network (of course, you might need to configure your webserver to respond to that hostname also)

Comment: That's not the only solution. A router knows its interfaces' addresses, and can recognize a packet incoming from one interface as destined for the same interface after NAT, thereby bypassing the external network altogether. This is called NAT loopback / NAT hairpinning / NAT reflection.